# Windows Phone 7 Reminders

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

Is there any way to set a reminder by Day of the week?  For example if I want a reminder every Friday at 10am.

What is the best way to accomplish this task?

I think I've been over thinking some sort of hours calculation.  I'm hoping there is a more simplistic way of doing what I'm looking to do.

Update:

My question is more about how to figure out how to set the reminder for a specific day even if it isn't today. So lets say today is Wednesday and I want to set a reminder for every Friday (or ANY day of the week)... How would I accomplish that?

Comment: Does this have to do with programming?

Comment: @CoreyFarwell - yes it does.  See answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the reminder needs a DateTime its pretty easy. Each application has a max of 50 reminders:

```
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Now; //First Friday at 10am
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
{
    Reminder reminder = new Reminder("MyReminder")
    reminder.Content = "Reminder";
    reminder.BeginTime = dateTime.AddDays(i * 7);

    ScheduledActionService.Add(reminder);
}
```

-or this may work-

```
Reminder reminder = new Reminder("MyReminder")
reminder.Content = "Reminder";
reminder.BeginTime = DateTime.Now; //First Friday at 10am
reminder.Content = "Reminder";
reminder.ExpirationTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(52 * 7);
reminder.RecurrenceType = RecurrenceInterval.Weekly; 

ScheduledActionService.Add(reminder);
```

#### EDIT

This is how you get the next *day of week*

```
private DateTime GetNextDay(string dayOfWeek)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        DateTime currentDateTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(i);
        if (dayOfWeek.Equals(currentDateTime.ToString("dddd")))
            return currentDateTime;
    }

    return DateTime.Now;
}
```

Comment: what is today isn't Friday?  My question is more about how to figure out how to set the reminder for a specific day even if it isn't today.  So lets say today is Wednesday and I want to set a reminder for every Monday...  How would I accomplish that?

Comment: ugh your question should be revised. This is a more general c# question

Comment: Then just change the Time portion of the return to x o'clock

Comment: That worked like a champ!  Thank you.  I will now use the GetNextDay with the Reminder code to do what I wanted.